# Hibernate access strategy for @Id property

Tags: hibernate, annotations

The Hibernate access strategy is specified implicitly by annotating the primary key attribute or its getter method with an `@Id` annotation. So depending on the `@Id` access strategy, it is applied to all the properties (or fields).

Is it possible to set `FIELD` access on the entity object but property access on the `@Id` property only? How should it be configured?

Answer (score 1):

According to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_overriding_the_default_access_strategy):

> The default access strategy mechanism can be overridden with the JPA `@Access` annotation.

And according to the JPA specification:

> **2.3.2 Explicit Access Type**
>
> An access type for an individual entity class, mapped superclass, or embeddable class can be specified for that class independent of the default for the entity hierarchy by means of the `Access` annotation
>   applied to the class. This explicit access type specification does not affect the access type of other entity classes or mapped superclasses in the entity hierarchy. The following rules apply:
>
> - When `Access(FIELD)` is applied to an entity class, mapped superclass, or embeddable class, mapping annotations may be placed on the instance variables of that class, and the persistence provider runtime accesses persistent state via the instance variables defined by the class. All non-transient instance variables that are not annotated with the Transient annotation
>     are persistent. *When `Access(FIELD)` is applied to such a class, it is possible to selectively designate individual attributes within the class for property access. To specify a persistent property for access by the persistence provider runtime, that property must be designated
>     `Access(PROPERTY)`.* The behavior is undefined if mapping annotations are placed on any properties defined by the class for which `Access(PROPERTY)` is not specified. Persistent state inherited from superclasses is accessed in accordance with the access types of those superclasses.
>
> ...

So, you can do something like this:

```java
@Entity(name = "Book")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public static class Book {

    // ...

    @Id
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks! But in example in documentation you pointed to the access strategy on object level was set by `@Id` annotation. And was overridden on the field level. If we put `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` on the object level will it have higher priority over `@Id` annotation?

Comment: @Alterant I have updated my answer by adding a confirmation from JPA spec. But to be honest I did not test it.

Comment: Thanks! We appreciate your help!